# Javascript: Wait until one function in first js file is complete before running function in second file

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 js file, script.js and index.js. In script.js I am returning a window object to then be used in the second js file.

```
function text (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    let row = [];
    let target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR"){
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if(target){
            let cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td');

        for (let i =0; i < cells.length-2; i++){
            row.push(cells[i].innerHTML)
        }
    }
    window.data= {
        last: row[0],
        party:row[1],
        number:row[2]
    }
    console.log(window.data)
};
```

my second js fie (index), right now, is just

```
alert(window.data)
```

It is undefined since text is a function assigned to an event listener.How can I wait until the button click/ text() is ran in the first js script, to then log/ use the window object in the second js script?
Here is full script.js

```
const btn = document.getElementById("addRow")
btn.addEventListener("click", addRow)

function addRow() {
    let name = document.getElementById("lastName").value
    let party = document.getElementById("party").value
    let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value
    const table = document.getElementById('table')
    console.log(name, party, phone)

    let elem = document.createElement('select')
    let optArray = ['Table Is Ready', 'Please Come See The Host', 'Your Table Will Be Ready Soon' ]
    elem.className = "select"
    for (let i =0; i <optArray.length; i++){
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = optArray[i]
        option.text = optArray[i];
        elem.appendChild(option);
    }

    let action = document.createElement('button')
    action.innerHTML = "Send Message";
    action.onclick = text;

    let newRow = table.insertRow(1)

    let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0)
    let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1)
    let cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2)
    let cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3)
    let cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4)

    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = party;
    cell3.innerHTML = phone;
    cell4.appendChild(elem)
    cell5.appendChild(action)



document.getElementById("lastName").value = ''
document.getElementById("party").value = ''
document.getElementById("phone").value = ''
}

function text (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    let row = [];
    let target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR"){
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if(target){
            let cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td');

        for (let i =0; i < cells.length-2; i++){
            row.push(cells[i].innerHTML)
        }
    }
    window.data= {
        last: row[0],
        party:row[1],
        number:row[2]
    }
    console.log(window.data)
};
```

Comment: There are multiple ways of handling this, like dynamically loading the `second.js`, But the easiest option is to make `second.js` into a function and then call the function..

Comment: @Keith call second.js in the first js file?

Comment: Yes, inside `second.js` do -> `function callSecond() { alert(window.data); }`, and then after doing `window.data = ...` do `callSecond()`.

Comment: @Keith can you re-write that as the answer, so I can mark it? Thank you

Comment: @uplusion23 has created a nice answer basically doing what I mentioned.   That would be good to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but assuming you want to use data produced by your `text()` function within another JS file, the steps should be simple.

First, load the script.js [The one with the `text()` function] second, and have the `index.js` file first. Example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Then, when `text()` has finished, where you have '`console.log(window.data)`', instead call a new function created in your `index.js`.

`index.js`

```js
// ...
function text (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    let row = [];
    let target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR"){
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if(target){
            let cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td');

        for (let i =0; i < cells.length-2; i++){
            row.push(cells[i].innerHTML)
        }
    }
    window.data= {
        last: row[0],
        party:row[1],
        number:row[2]
    }
    loadedFunction(window.data);
};
```

`script.js`

```
// alert(window.data);
const loadedFunction = (data) => {
  alert(data);
  // Manipulate or use 'data' here.
}
```